# Divide Dataframe into 2 dataframe using index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to divide my dataframe into 2 dataframe based on their index

```
Df1 with this index:[5, 15, 22, 23, 24]
Df2 with this index:[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
```

Unable to find solution! Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If input is list of index values is possible use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) (if not exist some values in original `index` also working correct):

```
idx = [5, 15, 22, 23, 24]

mask = df.index.isin(idx)

df1 = df[mask]
df2 = df[~mask]
```

Solution with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is possible without `:` and is necessary all values exist in original `index`:

```
L1 = [5, 15, 22, 23, 24]
L2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
      21, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
      41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
df1 = df.loc[L1]
df2 = df.loc[L2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .loc:

```py
df_1 = df.loc[[5, 15, 22, 23, 24], :]
df_2 = df.loc[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54], :]
```

Here is the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html